# how can i get api key for using Aviary SDK in my ios application

Tags: adobe, adobecreativesdk

i so far downloaded AVIARY SDK from official url and also the sample demo but it displays alert **Invalid api key and secret**

I also registering my demo IOS app in adobecCreativeSDK.Com  and get client secret key as well as client id then add keys in my app for use but displays same alert  **Invalid api key and secret**.

The screenshot is :

[image: tHIS aLert is displaying wHEN i CHOOSE PHOTO FROM CAMERA ROLL while set both client secret as a api key and client id as a secret key in my app but demo cannot run so how can remove alert from demo of AVAIRY in iOS ALERT IS DIPLAY AS UNDER:]

so, can anyone help for how to resolve this alert. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you got any kind of solutions? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and was searching for a solution. I finally  resolved my issue.

Check your code:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        AdobeUXAuthManager *authManager = [AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager];
        [authManager setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:@"*****************" clientSecret:@"***************" enableSignUp:YES];
        //        [AVYPhotoEditorController setAPIKey:@"" secret:@""];
    });
```

In my case, there was a white space in the Client ID. After I removed the white space, the issue was solved.